# How to use Jetty's ContentExchange to send SOAP request

Tags: soap, asynchronous, jetty

I am using Jetty's ContentExchange to send async http requests. I figured out how to send simple requests by just setting url. But for SOAP request, I am not sure how to set up the ContentExchange object. I searched but did not find any useful info. Please let me know if you have such experience or have some sample code to share. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post what you have already tried?

Comment: ok. I figured it out. It is not that hard. Basically, I just need to set headers and compose SOAP envelope as message body.

Comment: If you've figured it out, post what you've done in an answer below. some of us don't know how to solve similar problems and want to look at how you solved it (it's not just you that has problems in coding)